# webRTC in Chrome iOS

Tags: ios, webrtc

Why can I not make a webRTC call from my Chrome running on iOS phone? 
I can start a webrtc call in Safari, but when I start same link in chrome it does not work. Chrome does support webrtc, but when in iOS, it does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome on iOS is using a webkit webview which does not expose getUserMedia.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752458 is the chrome bug tracking this issue.

Comment: Exactly , Chrome uses webkit provided by apple and webview doesn't support webrtc.

Comment: iOS Chrome webkit does not have support for the webrtc. It is only for Safari!

Comment: Also see:  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208667 this thread is hilarious - so many people where this bug is a deal breaker for them, causing them to recommend Android to clients. It looks like one of the issues was fixed in the latest iOS 13 update but there is an issue with getMediaDevices that is currently being escalated to Apple. Hopefully it should be fixed by iOS 14,  but if this is predatory behaviour from Apple we may not see a fix.

Answer (score 12):

As of `iOS 14.3`, Chrome supports `webrtc` camera and microphone access, along with Safari that had already supported it.

This is a most welcome addition, because for years, Apple did not expose these features to Google, while at the same time requiring them to use the `Webkit` engine.

Answer (score 4):

iOS Chrome webkit does not have support for the webrtc. It is only for Safari!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome on desktop supports iOS

But in iOS **Safari** Only supports.

Other browsers don’t and can’t support WebRTC on iOS.

That’s because the supplied iOS Webview(UIWebview/WkWebView) still doesn’t support WebRTC (or disables it on purpose).