# HTML5 video with RTSP stream source not playing in Chrome on iPhone ios 13.4 but working in Safari

Tags: html5-video, webrtc, ios13, wowza, webrtc-ios

Developing a browser based webrtc streaming system, managed to get it all working properly and allows streaming from all devices. But my problem is on playback: all desktop browsers play it fine, chrome firefox on windows, chrome firefox safari on MacOs, works fine on android devices using chrome or firefox, but on iPhone/iPad iOS 13.4 it will only play in Safari. There are plenty of users using Chrome as their preferred browser on iOS devices, so I'm trying to figure out what can be preventing the videos to play on Chrome( chrome version tested on iphone is Chrome v83.0.4103.88

here is a snippet of the video

```
<video autoplay muted playsinline loop type ='rtmp/mp4' preload='auto' id="testVideo" style="width:100%;height:100%;" data-setup='{"techOrder": ["html5"], "nativeControlsForTouch": false, "controlBar": { "muteToggle": false, "volumeControl": false, "timeDivider": false, "durationDisplay": false, "progressControl": false } }'></video>
```

video source is loaded via JS and stream type is RTSP, handled in a Wowza instance media server (V4.7.8), encoding h264 baseline profile/pcma

Can't really find much on stack, most people having similar issues have it with Safari and chrome works fine for them. My problem is Safari works, but only safari on iOS devices.

Any suggestion is much appreciated!

EDIT: streams are published in mp4 format

Comment: Do not post answers that solve problems within your question. Post it as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [webRTC in Chrome iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59190472/webrtc-in-chrome-ios)